# Border thickness using style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I am making a little project, in which I am using data validation. Now I am trying to make styling for `TextBox`, when the input is not correct. I want to make a red border around the `TextBox` and a `ToolTip` with error message, which I return from C# code.

I started with making the red border. I wrote this in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="ErrorTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"></Setter>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

But if I write it like this, `BorderThickness` property is changing inner border thickness of the `TextBox`. With the code above, I get this:

[image: TextBox with thick blue border.]

Is there a way, to avoid this, and get something like this?

[image: Target TextBox with thick red border.]

And in a way, that I can add that `ToolTip`, using the same `Style`.

---

EDIT:
Code of `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox 
   Grid.Row="1"
   Grid.Column="3"
   Margin="10px"
   FontSize="14pt"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Padding="5px"
   Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
   Style="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}">
   <TextBox.DataContext>
      <local:Data/>
   </TextBox.DataContext>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your example has borderbrush "Red" but you show blue

Comment: It looks to me that if this other color is appearing, is because somewhere else in your XAML you have defined Margin / Padding   and have some background color

Comment: Can you post the TextBox code you are using this style in?

Comment: @IlanKeshet That is the problem. I defined, that the BorderBrush is Red, but while TextBox is in focus, it adds that blue border. And if i increase BorderThickness, it increases thickness of that blue border inwards (it makes border thicker into text field of textbox itself)

Comment: @FelixCastor Code added

Comment: @TamBui I don't have any other styling in the code, except the one, that is added into the post :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue border that you see is the border of the `TextBox` itself, which is light blue by default in its keyboard focused state. The border is 5 dips thick, because you explicitly set it in your provided `ErrorTemplate` style. The red line around it is the default error template of the `TextBox`.

In order to meet your requirements, create a style like below.

- Set a general `Margin` of 5 dips to account for the border that is displayed on error, it could otherwise be cut off outside the container since it is just an overlay over the original `TextBox` and it is not resized.
- Set an optional default tool tip for the non-error state.
- Set an `ErrorTemplate`, which is a special template dedicated to the error state, where `AdornedElementPlaceholder` represents the original `TextBox` in the template.
- Set a trigger that changes the tool tip text to the validation error in error state.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxValidationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="There is no error."/>
   <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
               <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5">
                  <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
               </Border>
            </StackPanel>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Apply the style to your `TextBox` using the `Style` property.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxValidationStyle}" ...>
```

Here is a sample screenshot of the result.

[image: TextBox in valid and invalid state.]

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick.
And someone here tried to convince me, that TextBox has no blue border at all :(